# Merge values inside dictionary and rename the key

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the dictionary below I need to restructure it in order to have a new dicitonary with an entry of the user and another entry listings all the messages requested bu that user and the time. The dict I'm using is this:

```
dictio =   { "Items": [{ "user": "a@gmail.com",
                         "type": "Product Team", 
                         "message": "Developer",
                         "employeeId": "101",
                         "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access", 
                         "Time": "2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542" }, 
                       { "user": "a@gmail.com",
                         "type": "Product Team",
                         "message": "Developer",
                         "employeeId": "101",
                         "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access",
                         "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542" }],
             "Count": 2, 
             "ScannedCount": 5, 
             "ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "xx",
                                  "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
                                  "HTTPHeaders": { "server": "Server",
                                                   "date": "Fri, 22 Jan 2021 08:02:13 GMT", 
                                                   "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0", 
                                                   "content-length": "3533", 
                                                   "connection": "keep-alive", 
                                                   "x-amzn-requestid": "xx", 
                                                   "x-amz-crc32": "xx" }, 
                                  "RetryAttempts": 0 } }
```

My expected out is

```
{"user": "a@gmail.com", 
 "message_requested_Time":[{"message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access", 
                            "Time": "2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542"},
                           {"message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access", 
                            "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542" }]}
```

Code is below

```
super_dict = {"user":'', "mesage_requested_Time":[]}
for d in dictio:
    for l, m in d.items():  
        super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
super_dict
```

Another dictionary for testing

````
dictio={ "Items": [ { "user": "a@gmail.com", 
                      "type": "Product Team",
                      "message": "Developer", 
                      "employeeId": "101",
                      "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access", 
                      "Time": "2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542" }, 
                    { "user": "a@gmail.com",
                      "type": "Product Team",
                      "message": "Developer",
                      "employeeId": "101", 
                      "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access", 
                      "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542" },
                    { "user": "a@gmail.com",
                      "type": "Ops",
                      "message": "Developer",
                      "employeeId": "101",
                      "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access", 
                      "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542" } ],
        "Count": 2,
        "ScannedCount": 5, 
        "ResponseMetadata": { "RequestId": "xx",
                              "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
                              "HTTPHeaders": {"server": "Server",
                                              "date": "Fri, 22 Jan 2021 08:02:13 GMT", 
                                              "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0", 
                                              "content-length": "3533", 
                                              "connection": "keep-alive", 
                                              "x-amzn-requestid": "xx",
                                              "x-amz-crc32": "xx" }, 
                              "RetryAttempts": 0 } }```
````

Comment: what is the error you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictio =   { "Items": [ { "user": "a@gmail.com", "type": "Product Team", "message": "Developer", "employeeId": "101", "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access", "Time": "2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542" }, { "user": "a@gmail.com", "type": "Product Team", "message": "Developer", "employeeId": "101", "message_requested": "Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access", "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542" } ], "Count": 2, "ScannedCount": 5, "ResponseMetadata": { "RequestId": "xx", "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": { "server": "Server", "date": "Fri, 22 Jan 2021 08:02:13 GMT", "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0", "content-length": "3533", "connection": "keep-alive", "x-amzn-requestid": "xx", "x-amz-crc32": "xx" }, "RetryAttempts": 0 } }

res = {}

for k,v in dictio.items():
    if k == 'Items':
        for i in v:
            res['user'] = i['user']
            res.setdefault('mesage_requested_Time', []).append({'message_requested' : i['message_requested'], 'Time' : i['Time']})

print(res)
```

Output

```
{'user': 'a@gmail.com', 'mesage_requested_Time': [{'message_requested': 'Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access', 'Time': '2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542'}, {'message_requested': 'Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access', 'Time': '2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster and more pythonic:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

for user, infos in groupby(dictio2['Items'], key=itemgetter('user')):
    output = {'user': user,
              'message_requested_Time': [{key: val for key, val in info.items() if key in ['message_requested', 'Time']}
                                         for info in infos]}
```

you can avoid the import of `itemgetter` and use a `lambda` expression like:

```
lambda x: x['user']
```

however the `itemgetter` function is a little bit faster.